# Python global name not defined in first function, but is in second one

Tags: python, telnet

I am encountering a strange problem under python 2.7.10, here is the relevant part of my code:

```
...

#is called whenever the reinitscore() is called, and if the if statement is correct
def calculateWinner(d):
    scores = {}
    high_score = 0

    for key, value in d.items():
        try:
            scores[value].append(key)
        except KeyError:
            scores[value] = [key]
        if value > high_score:
            high_score = value
    results = scores[high_score]

    if len(results) == 1:
        print results[0]
        stelnet.send(results[0])
        return results[0]
    else:
        print 'TIE'
        return 'TIE', results

#is called once, then every 5 seconds automatically with threading
def reinitScore():
    threading.Timer(5, reinitScore).start()
    global leftKeyCounter
    global rightKeyCounter
    global frontKeyCounter
    global backKeyCounter

    values = {'left' : leftKeyCounter, 'right' : rightKeyCounter, 'front' : frontKeyCounter, 'back' : backKeyCounter}

    if (leftKeyCounter != 0 or rightKeyCounter != 0 or frontKeyCounter != 0 or backKeyCounter != 0):
        calculateWinner(values)
        leftKeyCounter = 0
        rightKeyCounter = 0
        frontKeyCounter = 0
        backKeyCounter = 0
        print "back to 0"
    else:
        stelnet.send("test")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if(len(sys.argv) < 3):
        print 'Usage : python telnet.py hostname port'
        sys.exit()
     
    host = sys.argv[1]
    port = int(sys.argv[2])
     
    stelnet = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    stelnet.settimeout(2)
     
    # connect to remote host
    try:
        stelnet.connect((host, port))
    except:
        print 'Unable to connect'
        sys.exit()

...

while 1:
    socket_list = [sys.stdin, stelnet]
     
    # Get the list sockets which are readable
    read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets = select.select(socket_list , [], [])
     
    for sock in read_sockets:
        #incoming message from remote server
        if sock == stelnet:
            data = sock.recv(4096)
            if not data:
                print 'Connection closed'
                sys.exit()
            else:
                #print data
                sys.stdout.write(data)
         
        #user entered a message
        else:
            msg = sys.stdin.readline()
            stelnet.send(msg)
```

So what is happening here : calculateWinner() is called by the reinitScore, and send via telnet connection a result. there is no problem with the telnet sending in the calculateWinner() function, but when I want to use the stelnet.send() in reinitScore() he returns this

#### NameError: global name 'stelnet' is not defined

It is very strange, that I can use stelnet.send in a function, just next to each other, and not in another one...

Also, my python is constantly giving me the

#### unindentend error

which is very annoying, because I only use tabs, and not any spaces, he even forces me to unindent parts (see end of reinitScore()) to accept running the code ...

I am using Sublime Text (changed to Brackets because of the well known "sublime" problem with invisible characters, but doesn't change anything) under macosx ...

Comment: Configure your Sublime Text editor properly. In Python the convention is to use 4 spaces for indents; a text editor would then know to do "smart indents" when pressing the tab key.

Comment: It is configured on 4 spaces already.. :/

Comment: But your code has a **tab** now instead of 4 spaces.

Comment: You would do well to look at how to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  As it is, we can't copy paste your code and run it to replicate - there are undefined variable names, bad indentation etc.  An MCVE will help you get the bet possible help.

Comment: It is really long and everything is working together, making an MCVE of what I have would take a lot of a time, plus, you require to establish telnet communication with an ESP device to get it to work too.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Sublime text config : Tab width : 4 spaces ; indent using spaces. That's what you mean isn't it ?

Comment: the pasted code fragment does not define `stelnet` anywhere at all, so I just have to believe you that it could possibly work in the **other** function.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I added some details concerning 'stelnet', I got some problems during the copy paste, some bits are not indented, but it is in my code :-)

Comment: Please don't use globals.

Comment: @jmeyer2k I am far from being a pro in Python, it's actually my first project, and it seems to works great like that, I know there are some "no-nos" to avoid, but for that global problem, I asked on here too back then, and we told me to use that, and it worked just great. :)

Comment: @ThaD5, I'm not 100% sure why you're getting inconsistent behaviour but it looks like stelnet is only set in a local scope, that's why you can't call it from whatever function you want. Make it global or pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Please do not ask the same question repeatedly. This is regarded as noise on Stack Overflow. If your question is closed as unanswerable or did not attract responses, then the first thing to do is to *improve the question*; some guidance for this is [given here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Low-quality or unanswerable questions will typically be closed, but can be re-opened if improved or clarified (as appropriate).